# Get related objects in Django and how to use Prefetch with related models

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, prefetch, django-debug-toolbar

models.py

```
class Press(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=600, blank=True, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Scan(models.Model):
    press = models.ForeignKey(Press, related_name='scans', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    main_scan = models.ImageField(upload_to='press/scans', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
class PressListView(ListView):
    model = Press
    context_object_name = "press"
    template_name = "press.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['press'] = 
Press.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('scans', 
queryset=Scan.objects.select_related('press')))
        return context
```

What I would like to achieve on the front-end of the site is to list all Press and as the cover image for each would like to use 1st `main_scan` image from the `Scan` model.

I know I can add `models.ImageField` to `Press` model, but I do not want to - in the admin I am using `admin.TabularInline` from Scan model that is attached to Press model.

I know there is documentation on prefetch but probably I am using it wrong and as well doing it wrong on the front-end in the template.

Question is how to make it very optimized, that the performance is best, hitting the Database just once.

Previously I was doing it this way and it worked, but this is causing 15 duplicated SQL statements for 15 objects - by using django-toolbar I am checking it which is highly inefficient as performance.

```
{% for article in press %}
{{ article.title }}<br>
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ article.scans.all.0.main_scan }}" alt="">
{% endfor %}
```

My goal is to hit DB once by prefetch or something. This code below does not work so views.py is wrong and HTML as well.

```
{% for article in press %}
{{ article.title }}<br>
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ article.scans.main_image }}" alt="">
{% endfor %}
```

UPDATE:
15 duplicates gone. 3 Queries after the optimization by using `Prefetch()`

[image: Queries after optimization]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `Prefetch()` you should assign a `to_attr` which is the attribute name that the *list* of prefetched objects will be available under. Currently the excess queries are a result of accessing the reverse relationship for the field `press` because you assigned `related_name='scans'`.

You'll be able to access the prefetched related objects if you rename the attribute to something like `scans_list`.

```
press = Press.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch(
    'scans',
    queryset=Scan.objects.select_related('press'),
    to_attr='scans_list'
))
```

Then in your template you will be able to do:

```
{% for article in press %}
{{ article.title }}<br>
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ article.scans_list.0.main_scan }}" alt="">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: In you answer you are looping through all scans - what I am trying to do it List all Press Articles (ListView) and each Press article has title and 1 image - that image is the 1st scan from what that Press article has - what you are doing - you are listing all Press articles and for each one listing all Scans that article has.

Comment: prefetch_related() got an unexpected keyword argument 'to_attr' - got this error (context['press'] = Press.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch(
            'scans',
            queryset=Scan.objects.select_related('press')),
            to_attr='scans_list'
        ))  and in the template it probably won't work you should not use [0] - it should be like this - {{ article.scans_list.0.main_scan }} instead of this {{ article.scans_list[0].main_scan }} - but first if you can fix that 1st bug.

Comment: @Radek I messed up a parenthesis.. fixed now

Comment: as I suspected you cannot use: `{{ article.scans_list[0].main_scan }}` - it must be this `{{ article.scans_list.0.main_scan }}` - then you going to get `Could not parse the remainder: '[0].main_scan' from 'article.scans_list[0].main_scan'` error, so when I changed yours to `{{ article.scans_list.0.main_scan }}` - it started working - thank you, is this the best optimization approach? It cut 19 queries to 3 which is perfect, curious if something else can be done :) - please fix the template tag and I am going to mark it solved.

Comment: No problem, are the other two queries from the press model as well?

Comment: Have added the picture to question, how it looks right now.